# Lookup to column on site collection does not contain contents

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, csom

I create a site collection column that itself has a lookup onto a list inside that site collection. I create this column using CSOM:

```
    string contextUrl = "http://company.example.com/sites/mysite/subsite";

    SharePointContext spContext = SharePointContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext(HttpContext.Current);
    ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(contextUrl);
    Web web = clientContext.Web;
    clientContext.Load(web);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    Web rootWeb = clientContext.Site.RootWeb;
    clientContext.Load(rootWeb);

    // Add List containing target column
    ListCreationInformation targetListInfo = new ListCreationInformation();
    targetListInfo.Title = "TargetListTitle";
    targetListInfo.TemplateType = (int)ListTemplateType.GenericList;

    List targetList = web.Lists.Add(targetListInfo);           
    targetList.Update();
    clientContext.Load(targetList);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();


    // Update Title
    FieldCollection techListFields = targetList.Fields;
    clientContext.Load(techListFields);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    // Create Site Lookupcolumns
    var techListID = targetList.Id;

    FieldCollection colSCFields = rootWeb.Fields;
    clientContext.Load(colSCFields);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    var lookupSchema = "<Field Type='Lookup' DisplayName='Magic' Required='FALSE' List='" + techListID + "' ShowField='Title' StaticName='Magic' Name='Magic'/>";
    colSCFields.AddFieldAsXml(lookupSchema, false, AddFieldOptions.AddFieldInternalNameHint);

    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

(for complete information I added all lines, but the crucial part start below `"// Create Site Lookupcolumns"`)

The site column is being created, but when I use a lookup onto that column on a list inside a sub site (manually or by program) **the dropdown from that lookup field does not display any content**. (The behavior looks like a lookup column being created before the target column exists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify WebId attribute value (set it to subsite ID) in the field xml definition, like this:

```
var lookupSchema = "<Field Type='Lookup' DisplayName='Magic' Required='FALSE' WebId='" + web.Id + "' List='" + techListID + "' ShowField='Title' StaticName='Magic' Name='Magic'/>";
```